# TypeScript and canMakePayment

Tags: typescript, payment-request-api

I'm trying to make a system that uses the Payment Request Api and for the most part its successful, but TypeScript doesn't seem to have a definition for `canMakePayment` under the `PaymentRequest` object.

Am I missing something or do I need to cast it to `any` so my Typescript builds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend writing a small `.d.ts` file and reference that while the library type definitions do not include the complete interface yet.

i.e. containing something like:

```
declare interface PaymentRequest
{
    canMakePayment(): boolean; // Or whatever the correct type signature is.
}
```

If you place it in an `@types` directory it might be picked up automatically. Else use a reference comment, e.g. `/// <reference path="payment-request-extension.d.ts" />`.

Answer (score 1):

I found `canMakePayment()` entry in TypeScript's code.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L9737

I'm not a TypeScript expert but I assume you can import this?